# Re-Register events in socket.io-client after reconnect

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have an socket.io-client application which looks like this:

```
var port = 1234;
var host = "http://host.com";

var ioc = require( 'socket.io-client' );
var isConnected = false;

var socket;

connect();

function connect() {
    socket = ioc.connect( host + ":" + port);
}

socket.once( "connect", function () {
    isConnected = true;
    console.log( 'Client: Connected to port ' + port );

    socket.emit( "status message", "Hello Server", function ( message ) {
        console.log( 'Echo received: ', message );
    });
});

socket.once( "disconnect", function () {

    isConnected = false;
    console.log( '[ALERT]: Disconnected from Server (' + host + ":" + port + ')! ');
});

socket.on("reconnect", function(){
    console.log('Reconntected');
    isConnected = true;
});
```

The problem is, that after the reconnect event is getting called, any other event is never being called again. Especially the "disconnect" event is never being called after a reconnect which is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `socket.on( "disconnect", function () {...` if you want it to *stay* registered instead of re-registering it.

You're using `.once` which implies that it will be called only once ever.

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener

> #### emitter.once(event, listener)
>
> Adds a one time listener for the event. This listener is invoked only the next time the event is fired, after which it is removed.

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly worked. I have no idea why I used "once" instead of "on"...